# How to break out of FOREACH iteration in a logic app?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I've got a JSON payload that I've parsed:

[image]

I then iterate through an array that is inside of my JSON:

[image]

**How do I break out of the foreach iteration?**

Comment: i've made a video in case further context is needed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivmV8PGkyJU

Answer (score 6):

It would help if you could clarify your specific scenario. E.g. in some cases you can use the [Filter array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#filter-array-action) action and then check wither the result is empty, or check only the first item from the result, etc.

If you do need to break out of the `For each` loop, you can initialize a variable = `true()`, then inside `For each` create a `Condition` and perform your logic only if the condition is *True* (e.g. your variable is equal to `true()`) - it will still go through all your items but skip the main logic if the condition is *False.* You can set your variable to `false()` inside your main logic where needed. You'd probably want to set up your loop to be [sequential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#foreach-loop-sequential).

There can be other approaches, some more exotic than others, but it all depends on specific requirements.

E.g. the logic can be refactored to use the [Until](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#until-loop) loop, etc.